# Is there an alternative way to use xpath with Cypress now that the official plugin is depreciated?

Tags: cypress, cypress-xpath

I recently learn't that the official Cypress plugin for xpath is now depreciated

Reference:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath

I was wondering if anyone knows of an alternative way to still use xpath with Cypress?

I've Googled an alternative but am always led back to the official Cypress plugin (cypress-xpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That repo has been migrated to https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/npm/xpath, but it was also deprecated in June